# Is there any IND-CPA secure stream cipher with a "standard" hardness assumption?

Tags: stream-cipher, chosen-plaintext-attack, factoring, hardness-assumptions

I've read our recent question: ["One-time pad using RSA and Diffie-Hellman functions"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34330/23623) which asks about the security of a particular way to convert RSA and discrete exponentiation into a stream cipher. The approach didn't work out, as expected, knowing that it was an interview question.

Now, the following question came over me:
**Is it (constructively) possible to create a stream cipher whose IND-CPA security can be directly reduced to a well-known number-theoretic assumption?**

To be clear: I'd like to know (out of curiosity, no deployment intended) whether there exists a stream cipher which is as hard to break as CDH (or another assumption) with no other assumptions (no random oracles, no constructed PRPs like AES, no constructed PRFs like SHA-2, ...) and if such a stream cipher can exist , I'd also like to know how to build it (e.g. give a brief description please).

---

Example assumptions: "factoring is hard", "the RSA problem is hard", DLOG, CDH, DDH

Comment: I'm open for improvements to the title of the question and / or any parts of the question (please just suggest an edit then).

Comment: There are many examples, e.g., Blum-Goldwasser is based on "factoring is hard."  More generally, any public-key encryption can be used to share a random seed for a stream cipher.  Such a stream cipher can be built from any PRG, which can be built based on any of the assumptions you list.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert, sounds like an answer too me...

Comment: I wonder if DualEC-DRBG fits the bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

[one-way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) perm[utation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) ​ + ​ [strong hard-](http://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2004/CRYPTO/1407/1407.pdf#page=5)core [functions](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/papers/1995/grs-conf.pdf#page=3)

[$\to$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator_theorem#OWF_.E2.86.92_PRG)
pseudorandom generator

$\to$
stream cipher

The keystream is concatenation of the strong hard-core function's values at

the iterates of the one-way permutation on the key. ​ ( k,f(k),f(f(k)),f(f(f(k))),... )